# how to read device token (parse.com) with phonegap/javascript iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm developing an app for iOS with Phonegap and I'm using parse.com for push notification with iOS SDK included with Xcode. In my app users can login and I need to know the device token of the users to send to them single push notification, I know how to send the device token with the user/password during log in but I don't know how to read it, I don't know if there is any way directly with Phonegap or if I need to read it with C and then pass to Javascript with a variable.

EDIT: I'm trying to use Malloc's solution, and i have this problem. i installed plugin via CLI but i don't understand how to use it. I create a sample page

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript> parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function(id) { document.write(id); }, function(e) { alert('error'); }); 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

but of course i obtain a white page because this code don't print anything. 
What i need to do if i want to assign installationid to a javascript variable?
thanks

UPDATE 2

Now I have this code in my sample page

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">

     var appId = p3Z10Nj2GdmfuxCX1a9liu5VlPadbvgW********;
    var clientKey = lFRl93OEDM0bFTVOKaA1iIXV4vuWS3S9********;
    //
    parsePlugin.initialize(
    appId,
    clientKey,
    function() {

    // The parse plugin is initialized correctly, query the installation id
    parsePlugin.getInstallationId(
        function(id) {
                // Installation id is correctly queried
                console.log('The installation id is: '+id);
        },
        function(e) {
                alert('An error has occured while querying the installation id of your device');
    });
    },
    function(e) {
        alert('An error has occured while initializing the parse plugin');
});

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

UPDATE 3

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(window).load(function() {
     var appId = p3Z10Nj2gm8siK;
    var clientKey = lFRl93OEDM0bFTVOKaA1iIXV4vu;
        //
        parsePlugin.initialize(
        appId,
        clientKey,
        function() {

        // The parse plugin is initialized correctly, query the installation id
        parsePlugin.getInstallationId(
            function(id) {
                    // Installation id is correctly queried
                    console.log('The installation id is: '+id);
            },
            function(e) {
                    alert('An error has occured while querying the installation id of your device');
        });
        },
        function(e) {
            alert('An error has occured while initializing the parse plugin');
    });
}
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the device related installation id. You may need to use a plugin for this.

The plugin I have used, and which worked as expected, can be found [here](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin).

After installing it with the CLI, you just call the parsePlugin.getInstallationId function which will return the installation id for your device.

Keep in mind that you will get ONE installation id per device but that doesn't mean that you have always only one. Since you may run the app on more than a device, each one has his installation id.

**Update:**

The plugin should be initialized before calling `getInstallationId`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        var appId = YOUR_APP_ID;
        var clientKey = YOUR_KEY_CLIENT;
        //
        parsePlugin.initialize(
        appId,
        clientKey,
        function() {

        // The parse plugin is initialized correctly, query the installation id
        parsePlugin.getInstallationId(
            function(id) {
                    // Installation id is correctly queried
                    console.log('The installation id is: '+id);
            },
            function(e) {
                    alert('An error has occured while querying the installation id of your device');
        });
        },
        function(e) {
            alert('An error has occured while initializing the parse plugin');
    });
}
```

Comment: i update my question with my actually code, I removed and the install again the plugin but nothing is change, I still have white page

Comment: Some points to check with some `console.log()`: - Check your code is being called and also make sure it's running after the page has finished loading like my updated code. Use the Javascript console to see if any error raised up and fix them before. Also, run `cordova build ios` before you test on your device.

Comment: for privacy i removed a part of my appid and client key from question

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a plugin as others pointed out, here is another plugin that does the same job.
https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-parse

PS: I am the author of the plugin.

Comment: thanks, i will try this. What i need to do after the plugin installation via CLI? i need to add cordovaparse.h and cordovaparse.m to Xcode project? i need to include some .js file in html header? what is the javascript code that I need to insert in html file to read the getInstallationId?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to do any of these, check the readme about installation. cordova add plugin does everything for you. After deviceready received (cordova js event), you can call the getInstallationId. I suggest you to read cordova documentation about plugins.

Comment: thanks, i read cordova documentation and i understand it but i don't understand how i need to use getinstallationid because on your plugin pages is only write "etrieves the Parse installation Id with success callback"

for example what i need to use if I want to print the installationid


thanks